# How use Crud with CodeIginiter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and am having a hard time understanding how to use crud for my application. Please give me some slack if the code I'm using is totally wrong as I'm very new, and been trying for a week already to figure it out.

I am able to create and insert data into the database, but am having trouble updating. If you guys can take a look at my code, that would be great. Thanks.

Here is my code:

login.php controller

```
<?php
class login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url','html'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        // get form input
        $email = $this->input->post("email");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");
        $image = $this->input->post['image'];

        // form validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email", "trim|required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // validation fail
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        }
        else
        {
            // check for user credentials
            $uresult = $this->user_model->get_user($email, $password, $image);
            if (count($uresult) > 0)
            {
                // set session
                $sess_data = array('login' => TRUE, 'uname' => $uresult[0]->firstname, 'uid' => $uresult[0]->id, 'image' => $uresult[0]->id);
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                redirect("Profile/index");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email-ID or Password!</div>');
                redirect('login/index');
            }
        }
    }
}


Profile.php Controller

<?php
class Profile extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','html', 'form'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');


    }

    function index()
    {
        $details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('uid'));
        $data['uname'] = $details[0]->firstname . " " . $details[0]->lastname;
        $data['uemail'] = $details[0]->email;
        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }

    public function upload_profile() {
        $input = $this->input->post();

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/'; //path were I save the uploaded profile pics
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; // allowed types that is mention
        //size of the picture by default
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['overwrite'] = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        // display error if the picture is not on the config (sample bmp)
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = $this->upload->display_errors(); // display the errors

            $data['upload_error'] = $error;
            if($this->session->userdata('account_id') != null) {  // if there is an account
                $this->load->model('profile'); //model
                $this->load->model('account'); //model
                $data['user'] = $this->profile->get_profile($this->session->userdata('account_id')); //get_profile is a function in model
                $data['account'] = $this->account->get_account($this->session->userdata('account_id')); //get_account is a function in model
                $data['view'] = 'users/settings';
                $data['title'] = "User's Settings";
                $data['error'] = $error;
                $this->load->view('masterpage', $data);
            } else {
                redirect(base_url('index.php/Profile/index'));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //if no error
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $updateProfile = array(
                'profile_pic' => $data['file_name']
            );
            $this->load->model('profile');
            $this->profile->update_profile($this->session->userdata('account_id'), $updateProfile); // update the profile of the user
            redirect(base_url('index.php/profile/index'));
        }
    }


}
```

user_model.php model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class user_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_user($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->result();
    }

    // get user
    function get_user_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->result();
    }

    // insert
    function insert_user($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
    }



    public function get_profile($profile_id)
    {
        $this->db->select()->from('profile_tbl')->where('profile_id', $profile_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->first_row('array');
    }



    public function update_profile($profile_id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where('profile_id', $profile_id);
        $this->db->update('profile_tbl', $data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }


    public function get_account($account_id)
    {
        $this->db->select()->from('account_tbl');
        $this->db->where('account_id', $account_id);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }
}


?>
```

?>

Profile_view.php view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/mystyle.css'); ?>" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url('assets/css/mystyle.css');?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/mystyle.css" type="text/css">
    <?php
    $autoload['helper'] = array('css_js');?>

</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="mascot">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/monstercode.png" alt="Green Monster Mascot" style="width:160px;height:32px;"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url('')?>">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Site/sites')?>">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Site/developers')?>">Developers</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Site/employers')?>">Employers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                <?php if ($this->session->userdata('login')){ ?>

                    <li class="right nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><p class="navbar-text">Hello <?php echo $this->session->userdata('uname'); ?></p></li>
                    <li class="right nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/signup">Signup</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <div class="well">
                <p>User Picture <br/><br/><br/>

                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>


            </div>

            <div class="well">
                <p>User Info<br/> Name: <?php echo $uname; ?><br/> Email: <?php echo $uemail; ?> <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>Profile Summary</h4>
            <hr/>
            <p>Name: <?php echo $uname; ?></p>
            <p>Email: <?php echo $uemail; ?></p>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            <hr>
            <h3>More User Info</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
        <div class="well">
            <p>Job Offers <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
            <p>Job Offers <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
        </div>



        // default.png if haven't uploaded profile picture
        <?php $profilePic = "default.png"; ?>
        // if already uploaded profile picture it will display
        <?php if ($user['profile_pic'] != null) { ?>
            <?php $profilePic = $user['profile_pic']; ?>
        <?php }  ?>
        // if there is an error in uploading
        <?php if(isset($upload_error)) { ?>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    Uploading profile image could not be completed. <?php print_r($upload_error); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            //display the profile picture
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/'.$profilePic); ?>" width="100" />
            // call the controller upload_profile
            <?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url('index.php/Profile/upload_profile'));?>
            <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" style="display:none;" />
            <label for="userfile" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Choose Image</label>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs" value="edit profile" />
            </form>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of pasting all your codes if you could describe the exact problem you ar facing with the error message that you are getting it would me much easier for people to help you

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know next time. here is picture of error [img]http://i.imgur.com/Gbe6bgJ.png[/img]          

http://imgur.com/Gbe6bgJ

Answer (score 0):

Look at this block of code

```
function index()
    {
        $details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('uid'));
        $data['uname'] = $details[0]->firstname . " " . $details[0]->lastname;
        $data['uemail'] = $details[0]->email;
        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }
```

You are olny sending users email and name to the view.
But in your view you are using this `<?php $profilePic = $user['profile_pic']; ?>` which does not exists.That is why you are getting undefined variable error.

**Model**

```
 // instead of returning $query->result(), return $query->row() which would return only one row
    function get_user_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->row();
    }
```

**Controller**

Instead of passing individual users details like you have done, pass the whole user object. You can show data in view like this `Email : <?= $user->email ?>`   That way you wont have to use hundreds of variable if your user table contains hundreds of fields(I know it can't have that many fields, its just to point out the issue).

```
function index()
    {
        $user = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('uid'));
        $data['user'] = $user;
        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }
```

If `profile_pic` is a field in your `user` table, you can always check by

`<?php if($user->profile_pic != null)`

Comment: hi thanks for helping im follwoing your advice but i need to know what the proper way to add this code to the view....

<?= Email : $user->email ?> 
This code does not make sense to me.

Comment: `<?= ?>` is short tags in php. it is same as `<?php echo  $user->email; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

This is in answer to the appearing Comments you have...

Your code in your view needs to be altered a little as you've put your PHP Comments outside of your PHP Tags and you've gone overboard with the php tags so that could do with some cleanup. You could change that...

From

```
// default.png if haven't uploaded profile picture
<?php $profilePic = "default.png"; ?>
// if already uploaded profile picture it will display
<?php if ($user['profile_pic'] != null) { ?>
    <?php $profilePic = $user['profile_pic']; ?>
<?php }  ?>
```

To

```
<?php
// default.png if haven't uploaded profile picture
$profilePic = "default.png";
// if already uploaded profile picture it will display
if($user['profile_pic'] != null) {
    $profilePic = $user['profile_pic'];
}
?>
```